# how to pass an image to multiple views in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I need to pass an image to multiple views throughout my MVC 4 project.
What is the cleanest way about this?
Image is saved as a byte Array.
I have the image being saved to the database (this is input by the user)
and I don't want to create a load of viewModels.
Please note this is an MVC 4 application using Razor2 views, in C#.

Comment: could you both clarify ? if I use Partial Views, won't that mean I can only use it with one other view within the same controller...... HttpSessions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go with something like this in your controller:

For downloadable files:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string name)
{
    byte[] image = GetImageFromDb(name);
    return File(image, "image/jpg", "image1.jpg");
}
```

For files included in a view/page:

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(string name)
{
    byte[] image = GetImageFromDb(name);
    return FileContentResult(image, "image/jpg");
}
```

And use it in your views like this:

```
<img src="@Html.Action("GetImage", new { name = "image1"})">
```

Comment: So that ActionResult would be placed in each controller collected to the different views yes ? name = column name in database or do I need to create an image name property in the model ?

Comment: You can add the ActionResult to one controller and specify the controller in the `Html.Action` method. The name of the image is something like the key in your database, but you can change that according to your database/model.

Comment: Apologies , for labouring over a few lines of code but , GetImageFromDb? should that be intellisense ? or would that not mean I have to declare the model thats holding the image in order to access the database value ? "key in your database", you mean the ID ? all I have for that model is a generated ID and the byte array..

Comment: You have to write the `GetImageFromDb` method yourself according to the database you use. Name is the ID you use to identify the image. If you already have the image in your model you can use that instead of loading it from the database with a new method.

Comment: Method used.... public AdminPractice Get(int id)
        {
            return GetAll().FirstOrDefault(a => a.ID == id);
        }...................................................................             public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
        {
            byte[] image = _adminPractice.Get(id).PracticeLogo;
            return File(image, "image/jpg", "image1.jpg");
        }...................................................................     <img src="@Html.Action("GetImage", new { name = "image1"})" />.......would that be correct ??

Comment: it's not picking it up, should I be using File(image, "image/jpg", "1") and then ("GetImage",new { id = 1}) in the view ......image id is 1

Answer (score 1):

Ok I was a little off the mark, but thanks to Raidri for leading me in the right direction.
Controller...

```
      public FileContentResult GetLogoImage(int id)
    {
        var logo = _adminPractice.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == id);
        if (logo != null && logo.PracticeLogo != null)
        {
            return new FileContentResult(logo.PracticeLogo, "image/jpeg");
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

View............

```
     <img src="@Url.Action("GetLogoImage", new { id = Model.AdminPractice.ID })" />
```

Comment: Right, my way was for downloadable files. I will edit my answer to include both methods.

Comment: This will only work for one view/controller, I don't want to pass the model around to every controller and view ? is there any way to store the image once retrieved without making multiple calls to the database for the same image ?